# Determing the Round-Trip Time value in a network

Tags: networking, tcp

I have the understanding of RTT, but I will like to know if the RTT value is only known at the sender side and can't be known at the receiver side. I have try shuffle through the web but can't find any concrete answer with good explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each side estimates RTT separatelly.

So if you are having a truly unidirectional communication (only sender is actually sending data) then no. If both peers are sending data, then each peer will be able to calculate its own value.